# AWS service for website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have website which I wanted to host on AWS. My website stores the data in back end in RDBMS/MongoDB and uses PHP/Javascript/python and etc...

My website will be receiving data from users and I will be using it for analysis. I want to do any installation.

Which is the best for my requirement AWS s3 or AES E2?

Answer (score 0):

S3 is just file storage, you can't run dynamic applications (PHP/Python/etc.) or databases on S3. You probably need to run your application on EC2, your database on either EC2 or RDS, and store your application's static files on S3.